# How to email a google sheet tab which is in a google spreadsheet containing many tabs in xls (excel) format?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to attach a particular google sheet tab that is contained in a spreadsheet with multiple tabs in an email using apps script. The attachment should be an excel file i.e. in .xls format.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

You can achieve this task with the following code. Please change the content of the first two lines to suit your case.

### Code:

```
function sendSheetTab() {
  var sheetName = 'sheet1'
  var destinationEmail = 'some@email.com'

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)

  var params = ss.getId() + "/export?gid=" + sheet.getSheetId() + "&format=xlsx"
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + params

  var options = {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
          "authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      }
  };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , options)
  var contents = result.getContent()

  var subject = 'Sending sheet: ' + sheetName
  var body = 'With Apps Script'
  GmailApp.sendEmail(destinationEmail, subject, body, {attachments:[{fileName: sheetName + ".xls", content:contents, mimeType:"application//xls"}]})
}
```

### Reference:

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [UrlFetchApp.fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [GmailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body)